# How to provide default value for a parameter of delegate type in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates, optional-parameters

In C# we can provide default value of the parameters as such:

```
void Foo(int i =0) {}
```

But, when the method signature is:

```
void FooWithDelegateParam(Func<string,string> predicate)
{}
```

How can we pass the default parameter:

```
void FooWithDelegateParam(Func<string,string> predicate = (string,string x)=> {return y;})
{}
```

But this won't compile. So, what is the proper syntax for doing so ?

Note: I'm trying to provide a way to specify an **input-string to output-string mapper** through a delegate, and if not provided I simply want to return the input string. So, suggestions on any alternative approach to achieve this is highly appreciated as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't, basically. Default values for parameters have to be compile-time constants. However, if you're happy to use `null` as a value meaning "use the default" you could have:

```
void FooWithDelegateParam(Func<string, string> predicate = null)
{
    predicate = predicate ?? (x => x);
    // Code using predicate
}
```

Or use an overload, as per Alireza's suggestion, of course.

Each option has different implications:

- The overload solution works with languages which don't support optional parameters (e.g. C# before 4.0)
- The overload solution differentiates between `null` and "the default". This in itself has pros and cons:

  - If the caller should never provide a `null` value, the overload version can find bugs where it's *accidentally* doing so
  - If you don't believe there will be any such bugs, the optional parameter version allows the idea of "the default" to be represented in code - you could pass a "`null` meaning default" value through multiple layers, letting only the bottom-most layer determine what that default actually means, and do so more simply than having to explicitly call different overloads
- The optional parameter version is simpler to express in an interface...

  - ... with the downside that the default value would still need to be expressed in the implementation. (This is somewhat common to the overload solution, mind you... in both cases, an abstract class implementing the interface could do the defaulting using the template method pattern.)

Comment: Jon I'm curious about the pros and cons of each one. Yours is of course an all-in-one method, easier to maintain and my method has no runtime overload. Anything else?

Comment: yaah, that's right. Just found that out myself too.

Comment: Perhaps being a non-native English speaker the problem is with me, but I had to read the list twice to make sure I understand exactly which article is a "pro" and which is a "con". Just saying - perhaps it's better to write stuff like `Pro: content... Con: content" just to make it crystal clear for the rest of us :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I think there's enough subtlety in all the different options that it doesn't really separate into "pros and cons" neatly. I'll edit it to remove the idea that it's a simple "pros and cons" list.

Answer (score 8):

You can't specify default value like that. Write an overload instead:

```
void FooWithDelegateParam()
{
    FooWithDelegateParam(s => s);
}

void FooWithDelegateParam(Func<string,string> predicate)
{

}
```