# How to pass a predicate as parameter c#

Tags: c#, delegates, predicate

How can I pass a predicate into a method but also have it work if no predicate is passed?  I thought maybe something like this, but it doesn't seem to be correct.

```
private bool NoFilter() { return true; }

private List<thing> GetItems(Predicate<thing> filter = new Predicate<thing>(NoFilter))
{
    return rawList.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You are asking for [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24978661/1997232), right? Otherwise, define `NoFilter` as `Predicate<things> and pass it`.

Comment: Create an overload `GetItems() { return GetItems(NoFilter); }`

Comment: You can have a default value of `null` and you'd have to check for that in your code.  Alternatively you could overload the method with a second one that doesn't take a predicate.

Comment: @Servy May be is not a dupplicate and the OP have an issue passing a delegate as parameter ?

Comment: You default value must be resolved at compile time. `new Predicate<thing>(NoFIlter)` is evaluated at run time because of the constructor there so it will not work however you put it.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel That's not what their question is asking.  Their question is asking how to ensure that the parameter is optional and that `NoFilter` is used when no parameter is provided.  They're not asking how to pass a normal delegate as a parameter to a method.

Comment: @Fabulous A default value needs to be *a constant*.  `new Predicate<thing>(NoFIlter)` *is* resolved entirely at compile time, but it's simply not specified in the specs as a compile time constant.

Comment: @Servy it never occurred to me that `new Predicate<thing>(NoFilter)` is resolved when the code is compiling. Now that you say it I can see how. Thanks

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn How is the question not a duplicate?  It's asking literally exactly the same thing as the duplicate question.

Comment: @Servy Actually I was, as the title says, asking how to pass a predicate as a parameter. I tossed in the optional bit to see how a null predicate was handled as well (which was addressed nicely in the accepted answer).

Comment: @davecove And that's just a duplicate of an answer in the question it was closed as a duplicate of.  You're simply demonstrating that the question was unquestionably a duplicate.

Comment: Just because two questions have the same answer it doesn't mean they are the same. Example of two questions with the same answer. What is `2 + 2` and `What it is 2 * 2?`  Same answer, two different questions. My question was about passing predicates, not about a compile time constant error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
private List<thing> GetItems(Func<thing, bool> filter = null)
{
    return rawList.Where(filter ?? (s => true)).ToList();
}
```

In this expression `s => true` is the fallback filter which is evaluated if the argument `filter` is null. It just takes each entry of the list (as `s`) and returns `true`.

Comment: Getting an error like this when I implement `Cannot convert from System.Predicate<thing> to System.LinQ.Expressions.Expression<SystemFunc<thing,bool>>`

Comment: Try `Func<Thing, bool>` instead of `Predicate<Thing>`

Comment: For no warning use: Func<thing, bool>? filter = null

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to this.

First, you need to adjust the `NoFilter()` function to be compatible with `Predicate<T>`. Notice the latter is generic, but the former is not. Make `NoFilter()` look like this:

```
private bool NoFilter<T>(T item) { return true; }
```

I know you never use the generic type argument, but it's necessary to make this compatible with your predicate signature.

For fun, you could also define `NoFilter` this way:

```
private Predicate<T> NoFilter = x => true;
```

Now the second part: we can look at using the new generic method as the default argument for `GetItems()`. The trick here is you can only use *constants*. While `NoFilter()` will never change, from the compiler's view that's not quite the same things a a formal constant. In fact, there is only *one* possible constant you can use for this: `null`. That means your method signature must look like this:

```
private List<thing> GetItems(Predicate<thing> filter = null)
```

Then you can check for `null` at the beginning of your function and replace it with `NoFilter`:

```
private List<thing> GetItems(Predicate<thing> filter = null)
{
    if (filter == null) filter = NoFilter;
    return rawList.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

And if you also do want to explicitly pass this to the method when calling it, that would look like this:

```
var result = GetItems(NoFilter);
```

That should fully answer the original question, but I don't want to stop here. Let's look deeper.

Since you need the `if` condition anyway now, at this point I would tend to remove the `NoFilter<T>()` method entirely, and just do this:

```
private IEnumerable<thing> GetItems(Predicate<thing> filter = null)
{
    if (filter == null) return rawList;
    return rawList.Where(filter);
}
```

Note that I also changed the return type and removed the `ToList()` call at the end. If you find yourself calling `ToList()` at the end of a function just to match a `List<T>` return type, it's almost always **much** better to change the method signature to return `IEnumerable<T>` instead. If you really need a list (and usually, you don't), you can always call `ToList()` after calling the function.

This change makes your method more useful, by giving you a more abstract type that will be more compatible with other interfaces, and it potentially sets you up for a significant performance bump, both in terms of lowered memory use and in terms of lazy evaluation.

One final addition here is, if you do pare down to just `IEnumerable`, we can see now this method does not really provide much value at all beyond the base `rawItems` field. You might look at converting to a property, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Items {get {return rawList;}}
```

This still allows the consumer of your type use a predicate (or not) if they want via the existing `.Where()` method, while also continuing to hide the underlying raw data (you can't directly just call `.Add()` etc on this).

Comment: i get an error on the after filter passed into the .Where().. assuming rawList is a list of String objects... cannot convert System.Predicate<String> to System.Func<string, bool> .. can't be the only one??

Comment: A Predicate<X> is the same thing as a Func<X, bool>. It should be convertible, or perhaps an overload or reference is missing. Otherwise, it's a simple change.

Comment: hmm... i feel there is something fundamental i'm missing here, can't even figure out what the shape of the thing i need to pass in to GetItems() should be... think i will open a new q!