# Find Predicate parameters

Tags: c#

Is there a way to find parameters which is passed in predicate variable. Lets say, I have this method;

```
  List<User> GetUsers(Predicate<UserModel> userPredicate)
    {
      // how to find what values are passed in userPredicate
    }
```

Function Call:

```
GetUsers(_ => _.Name == "abc");
```

How can I find that in predicate, Name property has been set to "abc" within **GetUsers** function?

Comment: no, a predicate is a delegate to check if the parameter meets the condition or not.

Comment: Where is the instance of `UserModel`?

Comment: what are you trying to do, maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: so, inside GetUsers after doing some baseline checks, I want to execute the predicate passed by the user, whatever it is.

Comment: does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761385/how-to-pass-a-predicate-as-parameter-c-sharp

Comment: why using a predicate then? are you open to other options? because there is a flaw in that design!

Comment: @FIrePanda, you execute predicate like this: `userPredicate(userModel);`, the parameter is passed by you(GetUsers), so why do you need to find it?

Comment: parameter may change.

Comment: You probably should be looking at Expression Trees (`Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>>` instead of `Func<UserModel, bool>`)…

Comment: Can I access parameters passed in Func<userModel, bool>?

Comment: @FIrePanda, from your post, the underline is extractly the passed parameter, maybe `GetUsers(passedInUserModel => passedInUserModel.Name == "abc");`is more clear?

Comment: This GetUsers method call another method which first gets users list then call api for each user to get details, I want to restrict api call by accessing what predicate has been passed and filtering at getusers level.

Comment: Do you mean there are several predicates `_=>_.Name=="abc"`, `_=>_.Name=="def"`,... and you want to restrict the user to pass only predicate like the first kind? Or you want to get `"abc"` inside a predicate?

Comment: I want the param name i.e. Name as well as value i.e. "abc" passed in predicate in GetUsers method.

Comment: But "abc" is a constant inside the predicate, it's not a parameter. The parameter is an instance of `UserModel` which you have already got from previous call to _the another method_ you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void GetUsers(Expression<Func<UserModel, bool>> predicate)
{
    var expr = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;
    var value = expr.Right as ConstantExpression;
    // this will be the value of that predicate Func
    var yourvalue = value.Value;
}
```

This is one way to do it, and you have to be careful about casting those expressions because it might not work if you change the body of expression.

FYI, I wouldn't recommend this solution at all to achieve what you need to do, there are better ways to design it but it gives you are looking for.