# Creating function to query with linq in a MongoDB Singleton

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm creating a singleton class to query mongo collections in a .Net 6 web api. Since my application will query several different collections in 3 different databases so I'm making a function that receives the names of the collection and database together with the query parameters.

```
public class MongoReader
{
    private MongoClient _client;
    
    public MongoReader(string connectionString)
    {
        ConventionPack pack = new ConventionPack();
        pack.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
        ConventionRegistry.Register("My Solution Conventions", pack, t => true);

        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    }
    
    public async Task<List<T>> QueryCollection<T>(string collection, FilterDefinition<T> filter,int limit = 50,int batchSize = 50) where T : class 
    {
        string[] collectionInformation = collection.Split('.');
        string collectionName = collectionInformation[1];
        string collectionDatabase = collectionInformation[0];

        List<T> list = new List<T> ();

        FindOptions<T> findOptions = new FindOptions<T>() { Limit = limit , BatchSize = batchSize };

        IAsyncCursor<T> cursor = await _client.GetDatabase(collectionDatabase).GetCollection<T>(collectionName).FindAsync(filter, findOptions);

        list = await cursor.ToListAsync();

        return list;
    }
}
```

The current class only has a function with FilterDefinition as parameter but I also wish for a similar function that would allow me to use Linq as an argument. How can i do that?

This is how I wish to call the function :

```
MongoReader _reader = new MongoReader("connectionstring");
int limit = 50;
int batchSize = 50;
List<RandomClass> list = await _reader.QueryCollectionLinqAsync<RandomClass>("DatabaseName.CollectionName", t => t.fieldName == fieldValue,limit ,batchSize );
```

This is what I'm trying to do , currently not working because Where() doesn't doesn't have ToListAsync() even though when using `MongoDB.Driver.Linq`:

```
    public async Task<List<T>> QueryCollection<T>(string collection, Func<T,bool> predicate, int limit = 50, int batchSize = 50) where T : class 
{
    string[] collectionInformation = collection.Split('.');
    string collectionName = collectionInformation[1];
    string collectionDatabase = collectionInformation[0];

    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    AggregateOptions options = new AggregateOptions() { BatchSize = batchSize };

    return await _client.GetDatabase(collectionDatabase).GetCollection<T>(collectionName).AsQueryable(options).Where(predicate).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
}
```

It seems the issue was the argument used in `Where()`, `Where(Func<T,bool>)` doesn't have `ToListAsync()` but `Where(Expression<Func<T,bool>>)` does. This is the working function :

```
public async Task<List<T>> QueryCollection<T>(string collection, Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, int limit = 50, int batchSize = 50) where T : class 
{
    string[] collectionInformation = collection.Split('.');
    string collectionName = collectionInformation[1];
    string collectionDatabase = collectionInformation[0];

    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    AggregateOptions options = new AggregateOptions() { BatchSize = batchSize };


    return await _client.GetDatabase(collectionDatabase).GetCollection<T>(collectionName).AsQueryable<T>(options).Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Please try out this link to give you a clue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761385/how-to-pass-a-predicate-as-parameter-c-sharp

Comment: do not update the question with steps taken from the answer since it made hard to follow what happens in the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but if you ask why `Where` doesn't accept `FindOption`, then it's because `Where` uses `Aggregate` behind the scene, not `Find`. This is why you have to specify `AggregateOptions` instead (which allow similar options). You have to pass them into `AsQueryable` method.

`ToListAsync` is a method in Mongo Linq Extensions. To use it, you have to add appropriate namespace:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

The full example:

```
namespace Test
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            var db = client.GetDatabase("d");
            var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("c");
            var result = await coll
                .AsQueryable(new AggregateOptions())
                .Where(i => true)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about AggregateOptions , it seems to be a paremeter to be placed in the AsQueryable and not in Where().  About the namespace, i'm already using it but it still doesnt have ToListAsync, only ToList.

Comment: you do something wrong, see updated working example

Comment: i => true counts as Expression not Func , it seems Where() has ToListAsync when you have Expression as parameter but not when the parameter is Func. How can I change Func into Expression?

Comment: After changing Func<T,bool> to Expression<Func<T,bool>> it started working.

Comment: The whole LINQ magic is about translating LINQ expression (ie tree) into Mongo query via visiting each tree's node and constructing required steps for Mongo query. It's not possible to do it with Func