# Provide default value for a parameter of 'Type' causes "Error CS1736 Default parameter value for 'eType' must be a compile-time constant"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parameters

In C# we can provide default value of the parameters as such:

```
void Foo(int i = 0) {}
```

But when we pass the default parameter for Type:

```
void FooWithTypeParam(Type eType = typeof(double)) {}
```

It causes

```
Error CS1736 Default parameter value for 'eType' must be a compile-time constant
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978661) that we can use a null value to provide an internal default value.

Current soloution is:

```
void FooWithTypeParam(Type eType = null)
{
   eType = eType ?? typeof(decimal);
}
```

But it is not visible to the user what is the default value!
Do you have any suggestion, please?

[image: Invisble default value!]

Comment: It's unclear what sort of suggestion you want, I'm afraid. You can't use a non-null `Type` reference as a default value, because it can't be a compile time constant. You need to decide whether you want to a) not have defaults at all; b) use overloading to sort of fake a default value; c) use null as the default and document what that means.

Comment: Two methods (one with parameter, and one without) - both with appropriate XML documentation - is likely your best bet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490130/why-typeofint-tostring-is-not-constant

Answer (score 1):

I could only do this:

```
public MyMethod(int a, Type typeParam = null)
{
     // Set typeParam with default value "int" if is null:
     if(typeParam == null)
        typeParam = typeof(int);
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I think I know what you want. You want something where the type IS defined during compile time, but you want it to be user adjustable.
It is called "Generics". Perfect just for this ;)

```
public interface Foo<T, U> {
    void foobar (T first, U second);
}

public class Bar implements Foo {
    void foobar (T first, U second) {
        //Stuff
    }
}

//Use this like....
Bar bar = new Bar<Double, Decimal>
```

Now for default values to the function, you can use null and not be worried about the right type displaying. The function parameters will show you what you input for U and T when you made the object. It also does type validation during compilation - Don't die of excitement :)

Also a link for reference.
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics